# How to convert to .pfx and .key files into .jks or pkcs12?

Tags: pfx, pkcs#12, jks, mulesoft

Am using mulesoft application and when am trying to consume https application i need to send certificates.

But the files i got from vendor are .pfx and .key files. not sure how can i use them as my application supports either .jks or pkcs12.

can someone tell me how to convert .pfx and .key files into .jks or pkcs12 files

Answer (score 0):

.pfx should be a pkcs#12 file that Java supports natively these days, and it is recommended over JKS or JKCES files. Just be sure to specify pkcs12 as the keystore type.

.key is probably a PEM. You may need a certificate file too to create the key-certificate pair. A possible way to convert is to use [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/) which comes with most Linux distributions and macOs.

Example:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out keystore.p12 -inkey mykey.key -in mycert.pem -name "mykeyalias"
```